# converting a CLLocationCoordinate2D type to number or string

Tags: cocoa, cllocation

I was wondering how to convert latitude and longitude values of CLLocationCoordinate2D to numbers or string values.
Iver tried a few different ways but they arene't working:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord;
centerCoord.latitude = self.locModel.userLocation.coordinate.latitude ;
centerCoord.longitude = self.locModel.userLocation.coordinate.longitude; 
NSString *tmpLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", centerCoord.latitude];
NSString *tmpLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", centerCoord.longitude];

NSLog("User's latitude is: %@", tmpLat);
NSLog("User's longitude is: %@", tmpLong);
```

This returns a warning by the compiler.

The warning is

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type
```

How do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what the warning is but it's most likely because you forgot the `@` in front of the NSLog strings:

```
NSLog(@"User's latitude is: %f", self.locModel.userLocation.coordinate.latitude );
NSLog(@"User's longitude is: %f", self.locModel.userLocation.coordinate.longitude );
```

Your updated code should be:

```
NSLog(@"User's latitude is: %@", tmpLat);
NSLog(@"User's longitude is: %@", tmpLong);
```

NSLog expects an NSString parameter which needs an @ sign in front.  Without the @ sign, the string is a plain C string not an NSString object.

Comment: Sorry Anna Karenina, about the confusion. I have updated information my question and added the warning. Please see above

thanks

Comment: The problem is indeed that you do not have the @ sign in front of the NSLog strings.