# Converting CLLocationCoordinate2D to a String that can be stored

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocation, nscoding

I'm trying to save the coordinates of a user while in one ViewController so that it can be used to create an Annotation that can displayed in another ViewController.

In the view controller that stores the coordinates I'm using the code

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject( Location, forKey: "Location")
```

In the map view controller that displays the annotation I'm trying to get the coordinates using the code

```
let Location = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Location")
var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
Annotation.coordinate = Location
```

It is telling me that the value of type `String?` to a value of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

So how do I convert the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates into a value of type `String`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a CLLocationCoordinate2D type to number or string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899232/converting-a-cllocationcoordinate2d-type-to-number-or-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way you can store Locations to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
//First Convert it to NSNumber.
let lat : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: Location.latitude)
let lng : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: Location.longitude)

//Store it into Dictionary
let locationDict = ["lat": lat, "lng": lng]

//Store that Dictionary into NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationDict, forKey: "Location")
```

After that you can access it this way:

```
//Access that stored Values
let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as! [String : NSNumber]

//Get user location from that Dictionary
let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

Annotation.coordinate.latitude = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees  //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
Annotation.coordinate.longitude = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
```

**UPDATE:**

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-User-Location-With-Pin) is your Example project.

Comment: So for some reason whenever I press the button on the other view controller to save the location and a segue is performed to another view controller that displays the map view the annotation isn't being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D:Printable
{
    init(coords : String)
    {
        var fullNameArr = split(coords) {$0 == ";"}
        self.latitude = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(fullNameArr[0])!.doubleValue
        self.longitude = (fullNameArr.count > 1) ? NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(fullNameArr[1])!.doubleValue : 0
    }

    public var description : String
    {
        return "\(self.latitude);\(self.longitude)"
    }
}
```

Then use as in your sample code :

```
    var coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 3.2, longitude: 6.4)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(coord.description, forKey: "Location")
    var readedCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(coords: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Location")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the latitude or the longitude (or both in a dictionary or a tuple). The way to wrap them in String:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate        
    var lat : String = locValue.latitude.description
    var lng : String = locValue.longitude.description
    //do whatever you want with lat and lng
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an sprint kind of formatting:

```
func Coord2String(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> String {
    return  String(format : "latitude : %f, longitude : %f", location.latitude, location.longitude)
}
```